# Unable to find the difference of two file lengths in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We are using below code and able to get size of the files but we are getting error when trying to get difference of it.

I am new to groovy. Can someone help me to understand .

```
stage('Calculate Opatch size')
        { 
        def files
        dir("${BuildPathPublishRoot}") {
        files = findFiles(glob: '**', includes: '.zip')
        def Size1 = """${files[0].length}"""

        echo Size1
        
        }
        
        def files1
        dir("${BuildPathPublishRoot1}") {
        files1 = findFiles(glob: '**', includes: '.zip')
        def Size2 = """${files1[0].length}"""

        echo Size2
                }
                
        def Size3 = Size1 - Size2
        
        echo 'Size3 is '+ Size3
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the declarations of the variables Size1 and Size2 outside the local blocks (which limits the scope of variables), e.g.:

```
stage('Calculate Opatch size') {
    def files
    def Size1
    dir("${BuildPathPublishRoot}") {
        files = findFiles(glob: '**', includes: '.zip')
        Size1 = """${files[0].length}"""
    }
    
    def files1
    def Size2
    dir("${BuildPathPublishRoot1}") {
        files1 = findFiles(glob: '**', includes: '.zip')
        Size2 = """${files1[0].length}"""
    }
    
    def Size3 = Size1 - Size2
}
```